# What is the proper way to design a database for a website that has multiple instances of the same table/collection for each table/collection?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

So I have a website that is separated into 5 different modes / sections / modules / compartments / etcs...

The user would be able to switch to each separate mode by clicking on an icon / link.

Each of the modes are basically a different instance of the website. In other words, they all have the same UI components and backend tables / collections.

And the data in the modes will NEVER have to communicate with tables of other modes. In other words, no joins between the tables of the different modes.

Suppose that all of the modes need to have a table called `TABLE_A`.

Designed option 1:

Each of the 5 modes to have their own version of `TABLE_A`:

- `MODE_1_TABLE_A`
- `MODE_1_TABLE_A`
- `MODE_2_TABLE_A`
- `MODE_3_TABLE_A`
- `MODE_4_TABLE_A`
- `MODE_5_TABLE_A`

Designed option 2:

Have only one `TABLE_A` with an extra column to record which mode the records belong to

`TABLE_A` { Column_ID, ..., Column_Mode }

Which design is the correct design in terms of speed of queries, etc.?

I have chosen to use no noSQL database which is MongoDB.

There will be a page on each mode that will display a list of items from `TABLE_A`.

Comment: Do you have duplicate columns for each mode?
If you have a lot of duplicates, you could put everything in 1 table and use numbers to refer to another table?

Also, one table would make maintenance easier I suppose? I have to admit though, I have never been in the situation where I needed to make a choice like this so I have absolutely no idea what is best for you other than that it should be normalized.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe either option would have a significant impact on query performance. The real questions are more around flexibility and supportability.

It is obviously easier to maintain a single table rather than 5 identical copies of the same table.

If the 5 modes ever diverged from a single, common model then having the data for all 5 modes in a single table will become more and more difficult to support and splitting them into 5 separate tables at some point in the future is unlikely to be simple.

Up to you whether supportability or flexibility are more important/relevant to you

Comment: can you also have a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69997802/why-isnt-having-2-separate-tables-instead-of-1-better-for-query-performance

Comment: In it I basically ask why it won't be faster to have more tables?